# Half filled circle with d3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am trying to create a half filled circle with d3.js to be like [this](http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/shapes/images/halfcirles2010_8.jpg).
I didn't find any example of how to do it.
How can this be done with d3.js?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with an [SVG gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp). All you have to do is define it and then use it as fill for the circle.

```
var grad = svg.append("defs").append("linearGradient").attr("id", "grad")
              .attr("x1", "0%").attr("x2", "0%").attr("y1", "100%").attr("y2", "0%");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "50%").style("stop-color", "lightblue");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "50%").style("stop-color", "white");

svg.append("circle")
   .attr("fill", "url(#grad)");
```

JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9ChXk/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer this is working fine. for my purpose i also needed to add "stop-opacity" with 0 because i wanted half of the circle transparent and not white. I hope it help someone.

Answer (score 2):

You may not even require d3 for this simple task. You may use this simple technique, Using Clippath on a circle, I have written it in details in my blog http://anilmaharjan.com.np/blog/2013/11/create-filled-circle-to-visualize-data-using-svg

Use Two circles one above another in a  tag.
Fill one with the color you wish and another with white or may be your background color just to make it look like its empty in there.
Then clip the later one using  with rectangle in it, assign radius few pixel less than the earlier circle.
Place clip path at the top left .. assign width equal to the diameter of the circle and height will be defined by your data.
The data will act reversible to the filling so you may subtract the actual data from your max. EG: if data is 20/100 do 100-20 so u ll get 80 in this way the empty part will be 80 and filled will be 20.

You may switch between height or width to switch between vertical or horizontal filling axis.

The HTML should look like this.

```
<svg height="200"> <a transform="translate(100,100)">
    <g>
      <circle fill="#f60" r="50"></circle>
    </g>
    <g>
      <clippath id="g-clip">
       <rect height="50" id="g-clip-rect" width="100" x="-50" y="-50">
       </rect>
      </clippath>
      <circle clip-path="url(#g-clip)" fill="#fff" r="47"></circle>
    </g>
  </a>
</svg>
```

I have created a jsfiddle to illustrate this at: http://jsfiddle.net/neqeT/2/

Comment: Please provide some text in case your link changes at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

create a div having id name id_cirlce and paste this code inside script tag

```
<div id="id_circle"></div>

<script>
var svg = d3.select("#id_circle")
         .append("svg")
         .attr("width",250)
         .attr("height",250);

var grad = svg.append("defs")
          .append("linearGradient").attr("id", "grad")
              .attr("x1", "0%").attr("x2", "0%").attr("y1", "100%").attr("y2", "0%");

        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "50%").style("stop-color", "lightblue");
        grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "50%").style("stop-color", "white");

    svg.append("circle")
         .attr("r",50)
         .attr("cx",60)
         .attr("cy",60)
         .style("stroke","black")
         .style("fill","url(#grad)");

</script>
```