# How to add half circle in D3 based on function arguments?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The basic example of my question builds on [this chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). The goal is to fill only half the circle with the group color.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17511614/half-filled-circle-with-d3-js) SO question explains how to make half circles.

Here's a snippet of the original code

```
var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));
```

Here`s adding a half circle

```
var grad = svg.append("defs").append("linearGradient").attr("id", "grad")
              .attr("x1", "0%").attr("x2", "0%").attr("y1", "100%").attr("y2", "0%");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "50%").style("stop-color", "lightblue");
grad.append("stop").attr("offset", "50%").style("stop-color", "white");
var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));
enter code here
```

How could I make this grad dependent on the `d.group`?
I tried

- A get_grad() function and have it return the grad
- A set_grad() function and have it set the fill attribute

However, I didn't manage to get either working. Who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have different elements with different gradients, you have to use the same data binding process to create the gradients themselves:

```
var defs = svg.append("defs")
    .selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("linearGradient")
    //etc...
```

Have in mind that IDs have to be **unique**. In the following demo I'm doing:

```
.attr("id", function(d) {
    return "grad" + d
})
```

... to create unique IDs.

In the demo, this is the part that you probably are interested in:

```
defs.append("stop")
    .attr("offset", "50%")
    .style("stop-color", function(d) {
        return colours(d)
    })
```

As you can see, I'm applying the stop colours based on data.

Have a look at the demo (which is **not** a force directed chart, but simply a demo with elements using different gradients):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var colours = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var defs = svg.append("defs")
  .selectAll("foo")
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return "grad" + d
  })
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "100%")
  .attr("y2", "0%");

defs.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "50%")
  .style("stop-color", function(d) {
    return colours(d)
  })

defs.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", "50%")
  .style("stop-color", "white");

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 25 + d * 62
  })
  .attr("r", 25)
  .attr("stroke", "dimgray")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return "url(#grad" + d + ")"
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

You can also play with the offsets:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var colours = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var defs = svg.append("defs")
  .selectAll("foo")
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("linearGradient")
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return "grad" + d
  })
  .attr("x1", "0%")
  .attr("x2", "0%")
  .attr("y1", "100%")
  .attr("y2", "0%");

defs.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(d) {
    return 20 + d * 15 + "%"
  })
  .style("stop-color", function(d) {
    return colours(d)
  })

defs.append("stop")
  .attr("offset", function(d) {
    return 20 + d * 15 + "%"
  })
  .style("stop-color", "white");

var circles = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(d3.range(5))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return 25 + d * 62
  })
  .attr("r", 25)
  .attr("stroke", "dimgray")
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return "url(#grad" + d + ")"
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Yes, but could we make it a function? I am considering multiple classes, so then the number of elements grows with N!. And the number of classes may change per dataset. This way, we might make 45 elements in advance whereas we only need 10.  ((10choose2)=45,(5choose2)=10)

Comment: Well, I just showed you how to make the gradient depending on the data, and that is what you asked in your question. Your comment above may be worth of a new question, in which you can better explain what you want.